# C Functions Won't Work Properly

Tags: c, function

for my code, the user will enter a flag argument and two files, input being a MIPS and an output to write to. The flag has 3 options: -v for the program to read the labels from source control(var function), -f to read the labels from flow control(flo function), and -b to execute both -v and -f commands. My problem is that the -b function won't execute both. Just one of them.

```
  void var(char *inputfile, char * outputfile) {
  FILE *input=fopen(inputfile,"r");
  FILE *output=fopen(outputfile,"w");
  /*Code Here*/
  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);

        }



void flo(char *inputfile, char * outputfile) {
  FILE *input=fopen(inputfile,"r");
  FILE *output=fopen(outputfile,"w");
  /* Code here*/

  fclose(input);
  fclose(output);

}


int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char *inputfile,*outputfile;
  char flag = argv[1][1];
  inputfile=argv[2]; //Argument 2
  outputfile=argv[3]; //Argument 3

  /* check flag argument */
  switch(flag){
    /* This case produces a list of labels of the MAL source program used as
       variables in the specified output file */
  case 'v':
    var(inputfile, outputfile);
    break;

    /* This case produces a list of labels of the MAL program used for the flow control 
       in the specified output file*/
  case 'f':
    flo(inputfile, outputfile);
    break;
    /*This case produces both case v and f*/
  case 'b':
    var(inputfile, outputfile);
    flo(inputfile, outputfile);
    break;
    /*Case if user types unknown flag*/
  default :
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid flag");
    //exit code                                                                                                                                                                                  
  }

  printf("\nCheck your output file");
  getchar();
  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: In `flo()`, you overwrite what was written by `var()` in the outputfile. You could re-open the output file in append mode, `"a"`. Perhaps it is better to open and close the file in `main` and pass the open file handle to the functions.

Comment: You need a {} block.

Comment: @MOehm I put the open and close file in main, works fine now!

Comment: Glad to hear that!